# Creating a list from an existing list if a condition is true in Python

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I'm trying to remove some items from a list,

```
list1 = ["CCC-C", "CCC-P", "CCC-A-P", "CCC-A-H", "CCC-J", "CCC-S-X"]
new_list = [i for i in list1 if (len(i) == 5 or len(i) == 7 or i[6] != "H")]
```

Unless any item in `list1` has length 5 or 7, or its 7th character is "H", it shouldn't be in `new_list`.

But the code above includes "CCC-A-H" item in `new_list`. Besides, it doesn't give "IndexError: string index out of range" error when checking i[6] for item "CCC-C".  Any ideas?

Regards,

Comment: len('CCC-A-H') = 7, that's why it is in the new list

Comment: Can there be items of length 0-4 or 6 in your list?

Comment: No, only items of length 5 and 7 are allowed. And items of length 7 shouldn't have "H" as its 7th character.

Comment: My question was not clear enough. I know that you just want to *keep* those, but could the others occur in your data source?

Comment: Yes, any items can occur in list1.

Comment: Maybe you should try to be more precise about exactly what you want in `new_list`. Right now, it's doing exactly what you say you want it to do.

Answer (score 2):

Boolean expression in Python is executed in following order:

```
>>> A() or B()
```

If A() returns True, there is no need to check B()

```
>>> A() and B()
```

If A() return False, there is no need to check B()

I hope it gives you some idea.

Comment: Then I have to write it this way?: new_list = [i for i in ranks if ( i[6] != "H" or len(i) == 5 or len(i) == 7)]

Comment: @alwbtc: If you want to encounter an `IndexError`, then yes.

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you really want to do. If items of length 5 are supposed to be allowed, then isn't it better that you don't try to check `i[6]`?

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
new_list = [i for i in list1 if len(i)==5 or (len(i)==7 and i[6]!="H")]
```

That way, you only get the items that are of length 5 (condition `len(i)==5`) or items that are of length 7, unless the last character is an `H` (condition `(len(i)==7 and i[6]!="H")`).

The potentially `IndexError`-prone condition `i[6]!="H"` will only be evaluated if the string is of length 7, ensuring that you're not going to get this error.

Comment: I think it might just be possible that you're psychic.

Answer (score 0):

> Besides, it doesn't give "IndexError: string index out of range" error when checking i[6] for item "CCC-C".

`or` is short circuiting. If the first condition given for an or condition is `True`, then it doesn't compute the second, as irrespective of the the truth value of the second argument, the overall evaluated value remains `True`.

Also, "CCC-A-H" matches because, it's length is 7. If you don't want those strings that end with H in the 7th position irrespective of their length, you should redo your logical expression:

```
new_list = [i for i in list1 if (len(i) == 5 or len(i) == 7) and (i[6] != "H")]
```

Comment: But items that have length 5 cannot be checked with i[6], right? Thus, there will be an error.

Comment: The bracketing should be the other way, but you still want `and` rather than `or` the second time... **if** I've finally figured out what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, `len("CCC-A-H") == 7` and python employs short-circuit evaluation on boolean operations. The end result is that:

```
(len("CCC-A-H") == 5 or len("CCC-A-H") == 7 or "CCC-A-H"[6] != "H")
```

will return true because `len("CCC-A-H") == 7` evaluates to true before `"CCC-A-H"[6] != "H"` is evaluated.

This may be easier to see by using the `filter(...)` function instead of a list comprehension:

```
list1 = ["CCC-C", "CCC-P", "CCC-A-P", "CCC-A-H", "CCC-J", "CCC-S-X"]
def len57notHWrong(item):
    return len(item) == 5 or len(item) == 7 or item[6] != "H"

print "Wrong           : ", filter(len57notHWrong, list1)
```

This is a simple direct translation of the list comprehension you used to using the `filter(...)` function.

If we were to rewrite this using `if ... elif ... else` constructs, it would look something like this:

```
def len57notHWrongExpanded(item):
    if len(item) == 5:     # first check if length is 5
        return True
    elif len(item) == 7:   # now check if length is 7
        return True        # it's 7? Short-circuit, return True
    elif item[6] != "H": # This will never get seen (on this particular dataset)
        return True

    return False

print "Wrong (Expanded): ", filter(len57notHWrongExpanded, list1)
```

A correct expression would look like:

```
def len57notH(item):
    return len(item) == 5 or (len(item) == 7 and item[6] != "H")

print "Correct         : ", filter(len57notH, list1)
```

Expanded:

```
def len57notHExpanded(item):
    if len(item) == 5:
        return True
    elif len(item) == 7:
        if item[6] != "H":
            return True
    return False

print "Correct (Expand): ", filter(len57notHExpanded, list1)
```

This would make the list comprehension look like:

```
new_list = [i for i in list1 if (len(i) == 5 or (len(i) == 7 and i[6] != "H"))]
```

The reason your code doesn't raise an IndexError is because all of your data items are either 5 or 7 elements long. This causes the code to short circuit prior to hitting the `i[6] != "H"` expression. If you try this code on a list that contains data items that are not of length 5 or 7 and less than 7 elements long, then IndexError is raised:

```
list2 = ["CCC-C", "CCC-P", "CCC", "CCC-A-P", "CCC-A-H", "CCC-J", "CCC-S-X"]
new_list = [i for i in list2 if (len(i) == 5 or len(i) == 7 or i[6] != "H")]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/t.py", line 44, in <module>
    new_list = [i for i in list2 if (len(i) == 5 or len(i) == 7 or i[6] != "H")]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Sorry, it's a bit of a long answer...